# how to grep using linux

Tags: shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this line {"_class":"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer","crumb":"**acb6ecf3f5e2e90d6de6695a**","crumbRequestField":"Jenkins-Crumb"}

I want to gerb only the value of crumb in linux shell , How could I do that ?

I tried  grep ""crumb":" res.txt to take this line from a res.txt file

Answer (score 0):

That's JSON data, so use a JSON parsing tool. [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is a popular one:

```bash
line='{"_class":"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer","crumb":"acb6ecf3f5e2e90d6de6695a","crumbRequestField":"Jenkins-Crumb"}'
crumb=$(jq -r '.crumb' <<< "$line")
echo "$crumb"  # => acb6ecf3f5e2e90d6de6695a
```